# placeholder styling - override style that uses !important

Tags: html, css

I need to change the style of the placeholder in my framework. I need to override the instyle placeholder style the framework inserts for me. To do this I inserted the following code:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important;}
::-moz-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important;}
```

This works and makes all placeholders this style. The problem is I need for fields with one class to be another color. To do this I did:

```
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder .my_class { color:#000000!important;}
    ::-moz-placeholder .my_class  { color:#000000!important; } /* firefox 19+ */
    :-ms-input-placeholder .my_class  { color:#FFFF000 !important; } /* ie */
    input:-moz-placeholder .my_class  { color:#000000!important;}
```

This does not work though. The placeholders are still **#FFFF00**. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you using `!important`, just edit the original statement or repeat it after the original one with your settings and the cascade should take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `.my_class` before the `::-x-placeholder` pseudo elements

```css
input {background:red;}/*added for contrast */


::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important;}
::-moz-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#FFFF00 !important;}

.my_class::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color:#000000!important;}
.my_class::-moz-placeholder   { color:#000000!important; } /* firefox 19+ */
.my_class:-ms-input-placeholder  { color:#FFFF000 !important; } /* ie */
input.my_class:-moz-placeholder   { color:#000000!important;}
```

```html
<input placeholder="test"/>
<input placeholder="test" class="my_class"/>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works exactly how I want it to work thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vyDns/3/

```
.my_class::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: blue! important;
}
```